# texmaker can't install fancyhdr

Tags: texmaker

I am writing my thesis and when I compile with texmaker, I have this error:

> Unfortunately, the package fancyhdr could not be installed. Please
> check the log file:
> C:\Users\hicham\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Some lines of that log file are

```
2020-10-29 01:57:43,888+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: b097738edfa253d7c454fa07c81fc3c0
2020-10-29 01:57:44,907+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The requested package is unknown.
2020-10-29 01:57:44,908+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: ="name="fancyhdr""
2020-10-29 01:57:44,908+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageDataStore.cpp
2020-10-29 01:57:44,908+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 394
2020-10-29 01:57:45,066+0100 INFO pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1
2020-10-29 01:57:42,733+0100 INFO pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-10-29 01:57:42,835+0100 INFO pdflatex - installing package fancyhdr triggered by tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
2020-10-29 01:57:43,596+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-10-29 01:57:43,596+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-10-29 01:57:43,596+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
maintenance...
2020-10-29 01:57:23,402+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-10-29 01:57:23,402+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-10-29 01:57:24,030+0100 INFO pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: b097738edfa253d7c454fa07c81fc3c0
2020-10-29 01:57:25,600+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The requested package is unknown.
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What does the indicated log file say?  Maybe toward the end, if it's long.

Comment: i don't understand your question ? can you explain please ?

Comment: The error says: "Please check the log file: `C:\Users\hicham\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log`".  How big is that file?  What are the last 30 lines of that file?

Comment: i opened it in a "notebook", the file is very big!! i can not past it here

Comment: What are the last 30 lines of that file?

Comment: 2020-10-29 01:57:43,888+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: b097738edfa253d7c454fa07c81fc3c0
2020-10-29 01:57:44,907+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The requested package is unknown.
2020-10-29 01:57:44,908+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: ="name="fancyhdr""
2020-10-29 01:57:44,908+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageDataStore.cpp
2020-10-29 01:57:44,908+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 394
2020-10-29 01:57:45,066+0100 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1

Comment: 2020-10-29 01:57:42,733+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-10-29 01:57:42,835+0100 INFO  pdflatex - installing package fancyhdr triggered by tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
2020-10-29 01:57:43,596+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2020-10-29 01:57:43,596+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-10-29 01:57:43,596+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

Comment: maintenance...
2020-10-29 01:57:23,402+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
2020-10-29 01:57:23,402+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2020-10-29 01:57:24,030+0100 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: b097738edfa253d7c454fa07c81fc3c0
2020-10-29 01:57:25,600+0100 FATAL pdflatex - The requested package is unknown.

Comment: these are some of them

Comment: I edited the error messages into your question.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how else to help you.  If no one else comes along, you may need to reinstall TeXmaker.

Comment: It is not `texmaker` that is installing any packages. It is MikTeX. You might want to isntall fancyhdr via the miktex package mananger (miktex console). Given the error you get, it might be an idea to tell miktex to use a different repository to get the files.

Comment: @daleif i didn't understand !? do you have any solution of this problem ?

Comment: As I said texmaker has nothing to do with package installation it is your miktex doing it if a compilation says a package is missing. Here the auto install goes wrong and you're better off going directly to the miktex console to install the package/get a proper error message and not something texmaker is hiding fof you. I would suggest that you start by doing a full miktex update again something thst can only be done via the miktex console NOT via texmaker (as it is not involved in package installation, the package installation you see here are triggered by calling pdflatex)

Comment: @daleif i installed it via Miktex and it worked, thank you very much!